# Facebook Graph Api 2.4 Album Cover Photo in High Resolution

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve an Album cover photo in a higher resolution.
The following Graph API call does retrieve a cover photo:

```
{album-id}/picture
```

However, i can't get the picture in a high resolution. I've tryed:

```
{album-id}/picture?type=large
```

The Graph API Explorer tells me this:

> "(#100) type must be one of the following values: thumbnail, small,
>   album",

The 'album' type is a 180x540 image. I need a higher resolution.

### I figured out I can call:

```
{album-id}?fields=cover_photo
```

And get the ID of the cover photo, and then do a second call:

```
{cover-id}?fields=images
```

This will return all different sizes of the cover photo, and then I can inside my code get the resolution that best fits my needs.

However, I need to do 2 Graph API calls and yet filter the images inside my code. I tryed to filter the result with a '&width=961' but this doesn't seen to work either.

There's an easier way to get what I need?

Answer (score 6):

I imagine you can use the following call to get everything in one call:

```
/me/albums?fields=id,name,cover_photo.fields(images)&limit=100
```

This will return you the list of images for each album's cover photo. You can then select the first image in the `cover_photo.images` array in your application. this should normally be the largest size available.

AFAIK there's no way to filter any further regarding the sizes.